# CDF Player crashes on start-up Ubuntu 12.04 LTE

Tags: cdf-format, linux, crash, ubuntu

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, if not, please redirect me. I am trying to get [Mathematica's CDF player](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/download-cdf-player.html) running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTE (Precise Pangolin). This should be fairly standard and non-problematic. However, the CDF player keeps on crashing right after start-up. I Googled this and couldn't find any related thread.

**EDIT**: here is a terminal output of what is going on:

[image: screenshot of terminal window]

Comment: Does only the player crash or is the xserver crashing too? More specific: after the crash, is only the Mathematica Player window closed or are you back at the Ubuntu login screen?

Comment: Can you start the CDF player from the command line (ie. in a terminal) and paste the output, if any? This way we might be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @halirutan only the CDF player window closes

Comment: @mag I just made an update to the post

Comment: You should check that you have the GLX extension (mesa libraries) installed in your system. Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTE. Can I sudo-apt the GLX extension? (sorry, I'm quite new to Linux)

Comment: k found it with aptitude search. tried it out. then I get error messages about broken packages ;-). maybe I'll just forward this to wolfram.

Comment: I just installed it on my desktop computer, which runs the same distri of linux, and the player works fine. this means it's definately something about my notebook, maybe the graphics card.

Comment: If you have the t400 version with switchable graphics it might be worth to disable the intel one via bios and then use the radeon adapter only, configuring X for that. Other than that it seems a wrong X extension configuration issue on the GLX part. Also, sorry for the question about the distribution, you were crystal clear, I just need more coffee. :)

Comment: @mag: this fixed it! thank you! if you put this in as an answer I can upvote and accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check the GLX extensions (and the mesa libraries) of your X server.

Also, given the laptop you are using, I would definitely decide, if you have the version with 2 graphic cards, which one you want to use and configure X (and the GLX extensions) for that. I would suggest the Radeon one.

PS: 
noted as answer, while answer was given in comments, at Sebastian's request. :)